# Load Test software

Tags: testing, load

I know nothing about Load Test Software.

Is Visual Studio Load Test Virtual User Pack 2010 any good?

Comment: To get a useful answer you need to say a lot more about what you are load testing.

Comment: Sorry I am supposed to recommend some Load Testing software and we are already getting Load Test with the new MSDN lic.  so I wonder if it was good enough for load testing our applications or should we consider some other products like HP LoadRunner.

Comment: You can try the open-source Ddosify engine: https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify/tree/master/engine_docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you get what Microsoft gives you if you're committed to their stack.

If you want to spend additional funds you can try HP/Mercury tools like WinRunner and LoadRunner.

Or you can go the open source route and try JMeter or Grinder.